# Conpherence chat not updating in real-time in Phabricator

Tags: notifications, chat, real-time, phabricator

Conpherence only seems to update the chat when you write in a new message or reload the page. So for example:

- User1 and User2 open existing thread in the conpherence app
- User1 types a message
- User2 replies and Conference updates locally for User2, but User1 does not get the message
- User1 types a message, without getting the message from User2, and then presses submit, the conpherence app updates locally with both the message from User2 and message User1 created, but the message is not real-time received by User2. (This is then repeatable by both users)

Searched through a lot of issues in Phabricator and nothing has resolved our problem, we have our notifications server set up, we've set up notifications for Conpherence and done just about everything we can think of and still no real-time updating. Below are a few links we've looked at that may provide more insight.

[Enable notification Server](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T765)

[Improving Reliability of Messaging in Conpherence](https://secure.phabricator.com/T7755)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Link to bug report:
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T97650